# Autohotkey InStr() StartingPos

Tags: autohotkey

I'm having trouble with one simple autohotkey command.

```
aux_pos := InStr(nazev, " " [,StartingPos=20])
    MsgBox, space is at position "%aux_pos%"
```

It should start from 20th character, but I still keep getting as result position 7. There are many spaces after 20 in variable nazev, so there is not the problem.

Official Autohotkey help says

```
InStr(Haystack, Needle [, CaseSensitive = false, StartingPos = 1, Occurrence = 1]):
```

So syntax should be ok, as well.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: You don't include the brackets in the method, so it should be `InStr(nazev, "", false, 20)`, the brackets imply that those parameters are optional and do not have to be entered.

Comment: @Sidola That is the answer.  If you set it as an answer the OP can accept it.

Answer (score 3):

You don't include the brackets in the method, so it should be `InStr(nazev, "", false, 20)`, the brackets imply that those parameters are optional and do not have to be entered.